# XML parser, multiple roots

Tags: c#, xml, split

This is part of the input string, i can't modify it, it will always come in this way(via shared memory), but i can modify after i have put it into a string of course:

```
<sys><id>SCPUCLK</id><label>CPU Clock</label><value>2930</value></sys><sys><id>SCPUMUL</id><label>CPU Multiplier</label><value>11.0</value></sys><sys><id>SCPUFSB</id><label>CPU FSB</label><value>266</value></sys>
```

i've read it with both:

```
        String.Concat(
            XElement.Parse(encoding.GetString(bytes))
                .Descendants("value")
                .Select(v => v.Value));
```

and:

```
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(encoding.GetString(bytes));
    XmlNode node = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//value");
    Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);
```

but they both have an error when run; that the input has multiple roots(There are multiple root elements quote), i don't want to have to split the string.

Is their any way to read the string take the value between `<value>` and `</value>` without spiting the string into multiple inputs?

Comment: But you can only have one root in an XML document... otherwise it wouldn't be called the root of the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a well-formed XML document, so most XML tools won't be able to process it.

An exception is the `XmlReader`.  Look up [`XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel.aspx) in MSDN.  If you set it to `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`, you can create an `XmlReader` with those settings and use it to read elements from a stream that has no top-level element.

You have to write code that uses `XmlReader.Read()` to do this - you can't just feed it to an `XmlDocument` (which does require that there be a single top-level element).

e.g.,

```
var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, readerSettings))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        using (var fragmentReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            if (fragmentReader.Read())
            {
                var fragment = XNode.ReadFrom(fragmentReader) as XElement;

                // do something with fragment
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I've added an example to show how it could be applied.

Comment: i didnt mind at all! thank you! i finally got it to somewhat work! now it prints to CMD the xml formatted as: http://pastebin.com/z9DbSFUm (couldn't get format to work in comment) now all i need to do select the value node and print to CMD or string etc. much closer to my goal thanks!

Answer (score 2):

XML elements must have ONE root element, with whatever child structure you want.
Your xml string looks like:

```
<sys>
   ...
</sys>
<sys>
   ...
</sys>
```

The valid version would be:

```
<someRootElement>
  <sys>
   ...
  </sys>
  <sys>
   ...
  </sys>
</someElement>
```

Try:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<root>"+encoding.GetString(bytes)+"</root>");
XmlNode node = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//value");
Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);
```

Comment: its not working quite right, i get invalid character "." when it runs. the whole length of the string without the <root></root> is 3388(printed to TXT file on hdd to find that out) so i added 13 and got 3401(because thats how long the root tags are) Whole code: http://pastebin.com/9jvwP73e what im referring to is in the code so you may not get it see link

Comment: XmlElement node = document.SelectSingleNode("/Input/txt1") as XmlElement; worked better for me, but thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

This solution parses successfully all node types, including text nodes:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings{ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment};
var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
while(reader.Read())
{
    while(reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.None)
    {
        if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
        {
            reader.Skip();
            continue;
        }
        XNode node = XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
    }
}
```

Skips the XML declaration because it isn't a node.