# What values do I use when reading from memory mapped file? C#

Tags: c#, xml, character, root

so this the code snipit:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Memory mapped file reader started");

    using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AIDA64_SensorValues"))
    {
        using (var reader = file.CreateViewAccessor())
        {

            var bytes = new byte[3388];
            var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml("<root>" + encoding.GetString(bytes) + "</root>");
            XmlNode node = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//value");
            Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);

        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

it reads info like this from shared memory(snipit):

```
<sys><id>SCPUCLK</id><label>CPU Clock</label><value>2930</value></sys><sys><id>SCPUMUL</id><label>CPU Multiplier</label><value>11.0</value></sys>
```

and reads the value in all the `<value></value>` then prints it.
but its not working quite right, i get invalid character "." exception when it runs.

so i tried changing "new byte[3388];" the whole length of the string without the `<root></root>` is 3388(printed to TXT file on hdd to find that out) so i added 13 and got 3401(because thats how long the root tags are, which i had to add to fix multiple root error)

but i still seem to get error about "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 7."

thanks

Comment: You don't seem to be using `reader`.

Comment: document.LoadXml("<root>" + encoding.GetString(bytes) + "</root>");
In this line, how exactly are you filling bytes data? I mean in the code you have shown, bytes getting declared, but not filled up at all?

Comment: Why do you need a memory mapped file for this? Reading about 3K bytes from an XML file shouldn't need to do so.

Comment: this is being pulled from a windows system monitoring app, and this is how they store the data, as a xml ish formatted file in shared memory, i know it sucks.

Comment: encoding.GetString(bytes) i believe is thew answer zenwalker, the root tags are added because the xml doesn't have a Main root, just multipule roots( you can see multipule roots in the input xml as <sys></sys>) adding the root tags fixed an error i had when the program was running(multiple root exception on the xmlnode line) , now i have this.

Comment: if you dont get what i mean by the root tags see previous question/answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199047/xml-parser-multipule-roots

Comment: @Csharpz: No, that wasn't what zenwalker meant. `encoding.GetString(bytes)` reads from `bytes`, and returns a string. But where do you fill `bytes` with data? There must be some interaction between your memory mapped file and your call to `LoadXml` - currently there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few thoughts:

Your error is caused by non-printing characters in your XML string, which are causing the XML validation in XMLDocument.LoadXML() to fail.

Looking at the MemoryMappedViewAccessor class that is returned (reader), you want to be checking the Capacity property of that, which will be the farthest out you can read.   ReadByte() is okay, but if you know your data is ASCII, why not use ReadChar() and append them as you go to a StringBuilder object?

If the data itself has the invalid characters, there's literally no way to load this correctly during the read process, without first somehow sanitizing these characters from the string.   For a scenario like that, I would dump your buffer out to a file, then load that file with a tool like NotePad++ which has a "Show All Characters" function.   This will enable you to see specifically what characters and where (if they are outside of the normal XML, this might indicate you still don't quite have the buffers handling correctly).

Comment: well i dumped the string to a file, so i know it doesnt have any invalid characters actually in the string. im not sure, what is ASCI? what encoding would you use according to the sample of the input i gave? thankls

Comment: The encoding you use is dependant on what your source is.   Generally, the source should tell you, otherwise I would typically assume UTF-8 for XML.

What did you use to determine there were no invalid characters?  Just eyeballing it won't work.    If you pass the test that way, I would recommend loading that XML file directly into a test C# application through XMLDocument.Load() and see if you reproduce the problem.   If loading it as an XML file does not reproduce the issue, you have probably done something in writing it to a file that is cleaning out the bad character.

Comment: If you are cleaning it up by writing it to the file, those mechanics may offer a clue as to where that bad character exists.

Comment: XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel i used that to finally get it to load the fragments! for quickness purposes i just printed to CMD: http://pastebin.com/z9DbSFUm thats what i got!

Comment: ConformanceLevel will work up to a point, but eventually you will find cases where you have data loss/corruption due to the XML handlers being unable to correctly parse those characters (that's why they are invalid) - glad it works, but be careful!

Comment: printing to CMD will NOT show non-printing characters, you either have to use a HEX editor or an editing tool that is able to represent non-printing characters as something symbolic.   Notepad++ is my tool of choice for this, http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ It's free!

Comment: ok well the only thing Notepad++ showed was "NUL" at the very end of the output. and as im outputting to CMD with this new method (XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel) i get invalid error on that null character :(