# There are multiple root elements load xml

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

```
sRecieved = "<XmlClient>2.0</XmlClient><XmlVersion>3.0</XmlVersion>" 
Dim xml As New XmlDocument();    
xml.LoadXml(sRecieved);
```

There are multiple root elements .....i want xmlclient value and xmlversion value

Comment: whar are you trying to do?
sRecieved string should have valid xml

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199047/xml-parser-multipule-roots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, your data *isn't* a valid XML document. (The error message is pretty clear - you've got multiple top-level elements.) You could *make* it a valid document by adding a dummy root element:

```
xml.LoadXml("<root>" & sReceived & "</root>")
```

... but if you get the chance to change whatever's sending the data, it would be better if it sent an actual XML document.

EDIT: If you're able to use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument`, getting the client number and the version number are easy. For example, as text:

```
Dim clientVersion = doc.Root.Element("XmlClient").Value
Dim xmlVersion = doc.Root.Element("XmlVersion").Value
```

EDIT: Okay, if you're stuck with `XmlDocument`, I believe you could use:

```
Dim clientVersionNode = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("XmlClient")(0)
Dim clientVersion = (CType(clientVersionNode, XmlElement)).InnerText
```

(and likewise for `xmlVersion`)

Comment: thanx man...now i want value of xclient and xversion..any idea?

Comment: @faizanali: Well personally I'd use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument` - is that an option for you?

Comment: @faizanali: Wow, you're really stuck on .NET 2 or 3? Ick. Okay, will have a look at the `XmlDocument` API to see if I can remember it. It may not be nice VB though...

Answer (score -1):

This error is occur because there is no root element in your xml string.

Try this

```
sRecieved = "<xmlroot><XmlClient>2.0</XmlClient><XmlVersion>3.0</XmlVersion></xmlroot>"

Dim xml As New XmlDocument()

xml.LoadXml(sRecieved)
```